# WinUI 3 ItemsRepeater re-orders/removes items when scrolling within a ScrollViewer and using UniformGridLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, winui-3

Wanted to post my issue I have with WinUI 3 in .NET 6 here too, maybe it's not a bug and I am doing something wrong.

First of all a link to the issue on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4516

A sample project can be found here: https://github.com/brechtb86/microsoft-ui-xaml-issues

**Describe the bug**

When using an ItemsRepeater in a ScrollViewer on a Page within a NavigationView with a custom user control in the ItemTemplate and you start to scroll up and down, the items are re-ordered or even removed. The items are just simple objects and a UserControl bound to some properties of that object.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

Open the page "ItemsRepeater Scroll Issue (re-order/remove)". Items are ordered correctly.
Start scrolling up and down. Items are re-ordered and sometimes removed.
Switch to another page.
Switch back to page "ItemsRepeater Scroll Issue (re-order/remove)". Items are ordered correctly again.
Rinse and repeat.

**Expected behavior**

Items should stay in the same order.

I'm using the MVVM pattern, I'm using DI to manage my viewmodels with Ninject. The project is very simple:

ItemsRepeaterScrollIssuePage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="WinUI3Issues.ItemsRepeaterScrollIssuePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Issues"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:models="using:WinUI3Issues.Models"
xmlns:userControls="using:WinUI3Issues.UserControls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding Path=ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Start scrolling" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DummyObjects}">
            <ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                <UniformGridLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemsStretch="Fill" MinColumnSpacing="24" MinRowSpacing="24"></UniformGridLayout>
            </ItemsRepeater.Layout>
            <ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:DummyObject">
                    <Grid>
                        <userControls:DummyObjectControl Title="{Binding Path=Name}"></userControls:DummyObjectControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsRepeater>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

DummyObjectControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="WinUI3Issues.UserControls.DummyObjectControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Issues.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Border Height="288" Width="192" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel:

```
public class ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<DummyObject> DummyObjects { get; set; }

  public ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel()
  {
      this.DummyObjects = new ObservableCollection<DummyObject>();

      for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
      {
          this.DummyObjects.Add(new DummyObject(){ Name = $"Object_{i}"});
      }
  }
}
```

DummyObject.cs:

```
public class DummyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel => IocKernel.Get<ItemsRepeaterScrollIssueViewModel>();
    public XamlCommandBindingIconSourceIssueViewModel XamlCommandBindingIconSourceIssueViewModel => IocKernel.Get<XamlCommandBindingIconSourceIssueViewModel>();
}
```

Do any of you know if I might be doing something wrong or if this is a legit bug in WinUI 3?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got help on Github, the issue was that my dependency properties were not marked as static, another issue was that I didn't set the x:Bind mode to OneWay in my UserControl.